# Powershell - get the output of running a docker command (e.g. docker ps) into a variable

Tags: powershell, variables

The requirement is to record the output of a docker command into a variable.
Failed attempt:

```
$var = docker ps | Receive-Output
Write-Output $var
```

How would one go about recording the output of the command into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Expression`. [The `Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1#description) cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a command and returns the results of the expression or command.

```
$var = Invoke-Expression "docker ps"
```